# Is this application possible with the twitter api?

Tags: api, twitter, location

I have to make an application where a "sender" can send a message to a group of people and to a location. So when a member of the group reach this place (using location position with the cell phone), he receives all the messages for this location. I have thought to make the application using the twitter API, but I'm not really sure if that functionality is possible.

I thought using twitter would be nice to manage groups and login... the application is written in c++ in QT, so, any ideas for the service to be used to manage messages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like something you'd want to write independently; there's nothing using Twitter would really gain you here.

Answer (score 0):

ok... Here are some points from me.

1. First of all the person should have enabled geo tagging for you to get the position of the location.
2. The person should send a Tweet only then you will know the location of the person.

I wouldn't say its not possible but may not work in all cases. I would look for developing a service where the person can join, activate geo tagging and then you can monitor each  person's tweet and then send them this location based message.

Comment: thank you, i have updated the post, what service would you use to manage this messages? thank you

Comment: The service is the one which you will have to develop ;-)

Comment: Ok, but I mean, Im thinking in develop a webservice to manage all the requirements, so, what web service would you use to do it?